# How to recover a network device that disappeared in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos7, networkmanager

I have a set of servers installed in remote locations, with two ports, one that communicates with the internet, and the other that is typically set as a static IP for local connections.

Recently, it seems like the port for the local connections has just dropped off the face of the earth. I haven't changed anything, so it seems very strange. Here are some details. Typically, `ip a` has a 3rd result for `eno1`.

[image: list from <code>ip a</code>]

Here are the options from `nmtui`:

[image: list from <code>nmtui</code>]

And clearly `NetworkManager` is aware of the configuration, here is `nmcli c s`:

[image: output from <code>nmcli c s</code>]

Here is my `ifconfig-eno1` file (note temporarily set to `dhcp`, typically `BOOTPROTO=none` and `IPADDR=xx.xx.xx.xx` are set.)

[image: <code>ifconfig-eno1</code> file]

Here is what I see on network start:

[image: Error on network start]

Here is what I see on `systemctl restart network`:

[image: Error on network restart]

Here is what I see from `systemctl status NetworkManager`:

```
Nov 07 11:43:01 cinesend NetworkManager[14274]: 
<info>  [1573155781.9182] audit: 
op="connection-activate" 
uuid="10e7db30-105e-426c-8c1c-1485323c28a3" 
name="System eno1" 
result="fail" 
reason="No suitable device found for this connection."
```

- I've tried setting `BOOTPROTO=static` (but that seems incorrect).
- I've tried `systemctl stop NetworkManager && systemctl disable NetworkManager`, then `systemctl restart network`, and rebooting, etc., as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220750/centos-7-failed-to-bring-up-down-networking-configure-interface-for-a-trunk-in), to no avail.
- `ifup eno1` returns `Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.`

I have this thought that maybe the actual port has physically become disconnected from the motherboard.

Any other ideas?